# Permission denied altough chmod 777

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am running following commands:

```
$ ls
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx  3 szr szr 2.0K Nov 14 12:08 .
drwxrwxrwx 12 szr szr 2.0K Nov 14 11:23 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 szr szr 1.6K Nov 14 12:08 config.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 szr szr 1.6K Oct 23 01:13 config.xml.postinstall
drwxrwxrwx  5 szr szr 2.0K Nov 14 12:08 scripts
-rwxrwxrwx  1 szr szr  884 Oct 23 00:54 setup.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 szr szr   26 Oct 23 01:13 versionstr.txt
$ cat setup.sh 
cat: setup.sh: Permission denied
```

I don't understand it. Why cannot I access the file if permissions are set?

Thanks a lot for advice.

Edit: To explain the context - these files are from installation of pretty complex program that my friend installed on our server. In order for others to use it, we changed permissions recursively to 777 and I am now trying to run it. Pretty naive approach - I know - but at least I would expect different error to "Permission denied".

FOLLOW-UP

so this was the solution according to our admin:

find my_folder -type d -exec fs setacl {} my_user rl \;

It was afs filesystem, so usual commands did not work. Thanks for help.

Comment: Who is the owner of the files.  What group is connected to the file.  What is the file suppose to do exactly?

Comment: try getfacl setup.sh to see ACL.

Comment: Check the permissions of the mount too if this is a mounted device

Comment: .... or a network share?

Comment: @Perlnika - If you have an answer to your question, post an answer, don't simply update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was this (I know this from our admin):

find my_folder -type d -exec fs setacl {} my_user rl \;

It was afs filesystem (which i did not know before), so usual chmod commands did not work.